# What is a good way to share a database using Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

So I have a small test Postgres database in docker. I'm wondering what the best way to share it? Should I be using docker commit and then push it to the Dockerhub and share the image? Or is there a more preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends,

You can upload the image to Dockerhub, Docker images are pushed to Docker Hub through the docker push command. A single Docker Hub repository can hold many Docker images (stored as tags), but you will have two option for that :-

- **Private repositories** let you keep container images private, either to your own account or within an organization or team, and you add A collaborator which is someone you want to give access to a private repository
- **Public repositories** can be used to host Docker images which can be used by everyone else.

Comment: Most of the standard database images are configured so that you can't create a derived image with preloaded data (either in a Dockerfile or non-reproducibly via `docker commit`).

Comment: Oh ok, but this then sounds like in order to share the database I should push the image to dockerhub